# PHP upload input array and how to find how many files?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload

I have this form :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="photo[]" />
    <input type="file" name="photo[]" />
</form>
```

And I upload the files with php this way :

```
function upFiles($files){
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $files ; $i++){
        $FV_filename = $_FILES['photo']['name'][$i];
        $fileTYPE = substr($FV_filename , -4);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$i], uniqid().$fileTYPE);
    }
}

upFiles($_POST['howManyFiles']);
```

As you can see I get from the the client side how many files have been sent.
What I want to do is to check in the server side how many files have been received.
How can I do that? Is there any built in php function, if not then how to create one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
count( $_FILES['photo']['name'] );
```

should work. Alternatively, just rewrite your `for` loop to a `foreach`:

```
foreach ( $_FILES as $name => $file ) {
    var_dump( $file );
    // process file...
}
```

Comment: can you detail about the foreach ? what Contains $name and $file ?

Comment: `$name`'s the input name and `$file` is an array containing name, tmp_name, etcetara. You can always use `var_dump()` to find out what's in a variable; I've updated my example to show you how.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the file has been uploaded with `is_uploaded_file`, like so:

```
function upFiles($files){
    for($i = 0 ; $i < $files ; $i++){
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
            // uploaded file
        }
    }
}
```

You could use `foreach` to loop over all the uploaded photos instead of using a *magic number*.

From: [php.net](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: easier to just check for `$_FILES['photo']['error'][$i] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK`.

Answer (score 0):

**Iterate** over the $_FILES array:

```
function upFiles( $baseVarName ){

    foreach( $_FILES[ $baseVarName ] as $fileDetails ) {

        $FV_filename = $fileDetails['name'][$i];
        $fileTYPE = substr($FV_filename , -4);
        move_uploaded_file( $fileDetails['tmp_name'][$i], uniqid().$fileTYPE);

    }

}

upFiles( 'photo' );
```